# How to use c# to write a simple video player which plays the video with accurate fps?

Tags: c#, multithreading, video, opencv, emgucv

I'm write a simple video play with Emgu, which is a c# wrapper of opencv.

Now I can play a video, but I found the fps is not accurate, a little faster than normal.

In my code, I use `Thread.sleep()` to wait a while between 2 frames. The code is:

```
int fps = getFromFile(file); // which is 30
while (true) {
    var frame = CvInvoke.cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (frame.ToInt32() == 0) break;

    Image<Bgr, byte> dest = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Convert.ToInt32(width), Convert.ToInt32(height));
    CvInvoke.cvCopy(frame, dest, IntPtr.Zero);
    box.Image = dest;

    Thread.Sleep(1000 / Convert.ToInt32(fps));
}
```

Where is wrong, and how to fix it?

---

**update**

The `box` in the code is `Emgu.UI.ImageBox`, which is thread-safety, and I can access it from other thread directly: `box.Image = dest`

Comment: 1) Thread.Sleep is not terribly precise or guaranteed 2) The waiting time needs to account for the time not waited and other timing offsets, perhaps taking the total time into account (see #1) 3) Sleeping in the UI thread is generally not recommended .. and UI elements should only be accessed from the UI (creating, hopefully) thread.

Comment: 'Simple video' - does not exist.

Comment: It's funny you say it's faster because I would assume it'd be slower because you're sleeping for 33.3333 ms but the operations above the Sleep take time, too. You ought to sleep for (1000 / fps - <time taken for this frame till this line>).

Comment: @ananthonline, I thought it should slower than normal. But I open the same video with my player and a famous player, they started at the same time, but soon my player plays ahead.

Comment: You should know that OpenCV was not built for such things like video display. All the information regarding fps, number of frames, position in video is usually innacurate. The VideoCapture object is just meant to help fast prototyping image processing apps - it can load frames - but all the little details that make a good video player are missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a queue of frame objects 'topped up' and render them using a timer of some sort.  Usually, I would use a pool of frame objects that are continually recycled.

There is no simple video - vlc.exe: 13 threads, realplay.exe: 19 threads, divX player: 23 threads.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to use a timer

```
            _capture = new Capture(ofd.FileName);
            _videoTimer = new Timer();
            double fps = _capture.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
            _videoTimer.Interval =  Convert.ToInt16(1000 / fps); //the timer interval
            _videoTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(_videoTimer_Tick);
            _videoTimer.Start();
```

and now show this in an image box

```
private void _videoTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           Image<Bgr, Byte> img = _capture.QueryFrame();
            if (img == null) return; 
            box.Image = img;
}
```

Comment: I just use your code to write a new player. This time, it's a little slower than normal. Since `fps` here is 30, and `1000/fps` is 33, but the real one should be `33.333...`

Comment: I doubth that diff would be noticeable to the human eye. But you could adjust the 1000/fps * 0.85 or some factor like that.

Answer (score 1):

Timing an event at very small and accurate intervals is no trivial task, and Thread.Sleep certainly isn't what you want here.

First, Thread.Sleep doesn't guarantee your thread will resume in the specified amount of time, it just guarantees you'll be suspended for at least that amount.

Secondly, most timers are not accurate at the millisecond level you need here. These include System.Threading.Timer and System.Timers.Timer. You'll get jerky framerate at best using these. My solution of choice would be to write my own event loop with lag compensation using [System.Diagostics.Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx). This is fairly difficult but a good example is given in OpenTK's [GameWindow class](http://opentk.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opentk/trunk/Source/OpenTK/GameWindow.cs?revision=3117&view=markup). Another solution might the [Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742877.aspx), but those are not directly available from .NET and I have no experience using these.

Thirdly, don't use the same thread to post rendering events every 33ms and to actually render the frames; have a separate thread render frames continuously into a queue, and have a the timer thread simply pick the front frame. That way you free up the timer thread and allow it to be as accurate as it needs to be.